# Obtener Id de Select (Material-ui) seleccionado - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Amig@s, tengo un [select](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/) implementado con Material-Ui donde necesito obtener el `id` del elemento seleccionado, debido a que poseo una tabla que va aumentando su numero de filas dada una condición.

En resumen, no tengo problema en obtener el `value` y `name` del elemento mencionado, pero cuando trato de mirar el *id* siempre llega `undefined`, no así cuando utilizo un Select de `react-bootstrap` por ejemplo.

Les dejo un extracto del código

```
const [types, setTypes] = React.useState([])
const [data, setData] = React.useState({ fieldType: '' })

React.useEffect(() => {
   const aux = [
      { id: 10, value: 'GET' },
      { id: 20, value: 'POST' },
      { id: 30, value: 'PUT' } 
   ]
   setTypes(aux)
}, [])

const handleChange = event => {
   setData({
      [event.target.name] : event.target.value
   })
}

<FormControl className={classes.formControl} variant="outlined">
   <InputLabel>Tipo 1</InputLabel>
   <Select label='Tipo' id='tipo 1' value={data.fieldType} inputProps={{ name: 'fieldType'}} onChange={handleChange}>
      <MenuItem disabled value="">
         <em>Seleccione</em>
      </MenuItem>
      {types.map((v, i) => (
         <MenuItem key={i} value={v.id}>{v.value}</MenuItem>
      ))}
   </Select>
</FormControl>
```

**[Acá](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-brvlmh?file=index.js)** un ejemplo más completo :)

Como siempre, cualquier ayuda u orientación se agradece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar:

`event.currentTarget.id`

en vez de

`event.target.id`

Así cogerá el id perteneciente a `MenuItem` (en este caso 'tipo 1'). El ejemplo que has dejado entonces quedaría asi:

```
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { InputLabel, Select, MenuItem, FormControl } from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    formControl: {
        margin: '30px 0 35px 0',
        minWidth: '100%',
        maxWidth: 300
    }
}))

function Hello() {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [types, setTypes] = React.useState([])
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    fieldType: ''
  })

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const aux = [
      { id: 10, value: 'GET' },
      { id: 20, value: 'POST' },
      { id: 30, value: 'PUT' } 
    ]
    setTypes(aux)
  }, [])

  const handleChange = event => {
    console.log(`Id: ${event.currentTarget.id} | name: ${event.target.name} | value: ${event.target.value}`)

    setData({
      [event.target.name] : event.target.value
    })
  }

  return <React.Fragment>
    <FormControl className={classes.formControl} variant="outlined">
      <InputLabel>Tipo 1</InputLabel>
      <Select label='Tipo' value={data.fieldType} inputProps={{ name: 'fieldType', id: 'tipo 1' }} onChange={handleChange}>
        <MenuItem disabled value="">
          <em>Seleccione</em>
        </MenuItem>
        {types.map((v, i) => (
          <MenuItem key={i} id='tipo 1' value={v.id}>{v.value}</MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  </React.Fragment>
}
export default Hello
```

Comment: Diste totalmente en el clavo, pero cabe aclarar que el `currentTarget` hace referencia al id seteado dentro del componente `</MenuItem>`, no dentro del `Select`.

Comment: Cierto! Respuesta editada, gracias :)